# How to remote control a redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux

My setup is ReactJS + Redux.

I have a component named Gallery:

- Gallery.js: ReactJS Component
- GalleryContainer: Redux container

I want to control the selected tab in the controller from outside (far away in the component hierarchy). I added a variable in my **appState** reducer, an action creator named **setGallerySelectedTab** and I listen to newly arrived props in **componentWillReviewProps** and compare them to the state's *selectedTab*. I have two open issues regarding this approach:

1. **Hard Work:** each aspect of the component's look&feel I want to control requires me to create a new reducer property, action creator and willReceiveProps comparision.
2. **Cluttering:** a lot of setState for each aspect. It feels it makes the component more specific. A person reading the component's code wants to know what the component does and now he sees a lot of code that deals with external control.

Does anybody have a good idea of how to control a redux component while keeping the code elegant?

Answer (score 1):

It seams like `buy` should be an action creator, that all your components can use. If you've colocated it with your component because one depends on the other, you should probably decouple them by putting the state they share in the Redux store.

---

EDITS after the OP changed his post to better formulate the question.

You haven't given any concrete code samples, but you're saying you have to do a lot of setState. Why?

The way your component is rendered should only depend on the component's props and internal state. If a change in props requires a change in state, you can probably calculate these state methods from props inside your render method, and just not store them in state.

Comment: You're right. It uses other actionCreators but I can package it as a new action creator.

Comment: I still wish there was a way to control a component without listening to changes in props. For instance, if I want to change the selected Tab of a component from a far way part of the system... listening to prop changes for the sake of controlling the look&feel, I wonder if it's the elegant way to do this...

Comment: I am sorry. I've changed my question to make it clearer only to realize that your answer is now off context. I apologise.

Comment: @Guy To reply to your 2nd comment, I the point of React, is to make the flow of data easy to reason about. Your component is a function, whose output (look & feel) only depends on its props and internal state.